# How to Split on three different delimiters then ucfirst each result[]?

Tags: perl, split, delimiter

I am trying to figure out how to split a string that has three possible delimiters (or none) without a million lines of code but, code is still legible to a guy like me.

Many possible combinations in the string.

```
    this-is_the.string
    this.is.the.string
    this-is_the_string
    thisisthestring
```

There are no spaces in the string and none of these characters:

```
 ~`!@#$%^&*()+=\][{}|';:"/?>,<.
```

The string is already stripped of all but:

```
0-9
a-Z
-
_ 
.
```

There are also no sequential dots, dashes or underscores.

I would like the result to be displayed like Result:

```
This Is The String
```

I am really having a difficult time trying to get this going.
I believe I will need to use a hash and I just have not grasped the concept even after hours of trial and error.

I am bewildered at the fact I could possibly split a string on multiple delimiters where the delimiters could be in any order AND/OR three different types (or none at all) AND maintain the order of the result!

Any possibilities?

Comment: You'll need to use some basic natural language processing for the last possibility (`thisisthestring`). The other ones are much easier to work with.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I know you cannot spit a string without a delimiter! Did not have my filter switched on between thought process and reality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string into words, [capitalise](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) the words, then [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) the words while inserting spaces between them.

It can be coded quite succinctly:

```
my $clean = join ' ', map ucfirst lc, split /[_.-]+/, $string;
```

If you just want to print out the result, you can use

```
use feature qw( say );
say join ' ', map ucfirst lc, split /[_.-]+/, $string;
```

or

```
print join ' ', map ucfirst lc, split /[_.-]+/, $string;
print "\n";
```

Comment: Your suggestions are undoubtedly very succinct, but using map without an explicit code block and `$_` obfuscates what's actually happening there somewhat. Perl Best Practices recommends against use of implicit `$-` in all cases for this reason.

Comment: No it doesn't, it makes it abundantly clear without unnecessary noise, *assuming the reader knows Perl*, which has to be the assumption anyway. This is one of many cases where PBP offers silly advice.

Comment: @edb, A lot of suggestions from PBP are wrong or situational. Something's presence in that book is not an argument, and its author will be the first to tell you that.

Comment: @ikegami, yes, you're right. Where I work, we adhere to PBP with only a few exceptions. This has helped create a codebase that's relatively easy to maintain and simple enough for developers unfamiliar with Perl to understand quickly. For those more deeply familiar with Perl, some of its suggestions don't necessarily make a lot of sense. I suppose I was thinking of what would be easiest to interpret for our developers; depending Jim_bo's experience with Perl so far, your solution may indeed be easier to understand.

Comment: @edb, I often find I have to choose between: Use "advanced features" which require lots of attention to read for the less knowledgable -vs- using lots of code which requires lots of attention to read to due the sheer bulk of code. Since the former only affects some, I'll lean that way. I could change my code to use `map ucfirst(lc($_)),` without losing anything, but anymore and I see a loss.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple to use a global regular expression to gather all sequences of characters that are *not* a dot, dash, or underscore.

After that, [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) will lower-case each string and [`ucfirst`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) will capitalise it. Stringifying an array will insert spaces between the elements.

```perl
for ( qw/ this-is_the.string this.is.the.string this-is_the_string / ) {
  my @string = map {ucfirst lc } /[^-_.]+/g;
  print "@string\n";
}
```

**output**

```
This Is The String
This Is The String
This Is The String
```

Comment: `lc` is not necessary for the sample input, but it could be useful. (+1) Added to my answer.

Comment: The question says the string can contain `a-Z`, by which I assume he means `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Thank You. This helped me out with another issue I had!

Answer (score 2):

*" the delimiters could be anywhere AND/OR three different types (or none at all)"* ... you need a delimiter to split a string, you can define multiple delimiters with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html) to the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function

```
my @parts = split(/[-_\.]/, $string);
print ucfirst "$_ " foreach @parts;
print "\n"
```

Comment: Yes, that typed out wrong. Would that be \@parts or \$parts?  Then I need to foreach \@parts and lcfirst each?

Comment: @Jim_Bo, He was uppercasing everything, but I fixed that.

Comment: I see better now. You changed your code from `$parts =` to `@parts =` which was my boggle. I just discovered using the tick `forcode` and I mistakenly backslashed the \@ if that's what you meant? I will test this too. Thank you!

Comment: I like both answers. Yours and ikegami's . I have learned here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will work for all but your last test case. It's extremely hard to split a string without delimiters, you'd need to have a list of possible words, and even then it would be prone to error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = qw(
    this-is_the.string
    this.is.the.string
    this-is_the_string
    thisisthestring
);

foreach my $string (@strings) {
    print join(q{ }, map {ucfirst($_)} split(m{[_.-]}smx,$string)) . qq{\n};
}
```

And here's an alternative for the loop that splits everything into separate statements to make it easier to read:

```
foreach my $string (@strings) {
    my @words = split m{[_.-]}smx, $string;
    my @upper_case_words = map {ucfirst($_)} @words;
    my $string_with_spaces = join q{ }, @upper_case_words;
    print $string_with_spaces . qq{\n};
}
```

Comment: This looks promising but, will require much study. That said, I am off to test. Be right back.

Comment: Just let me know which parts you need help with

Comment: Perlfect! That worked even when I forgot to mention there are no possibilities of `_-` in sequence, I just mentioned like delimiters in sequence.  This works even with `.-_` in sequence! Now, to pass the result elsewhere, would I `my $string = join(q{ }, map {ucfirst($_)} @{[split(m{[_.-]}smx,$string)]}) . qq{\n};`

Comment: @Jim_Bo, Refer to the edited post. There's no need to create an anonymous array and a reference to it only to immediately discard both, so I removed that bit. His code contains a lot of other hindrances to readability (useless /s, useless /m, useless /x, needless `q{}` and `qq{}`, nonstandard spacing)

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for removing the array ref thing, don't quite know why I did that. As for the other hindrances you mention, consistent use of `smx` is recommended by Perl Best Practices. It allows regexes to be written more consistently. Using `q{}` and `qq{}` is not unreasonable either, using those, you never have to worry about quotes in your strings. Perl Best Practices also recommends use of q{} for empty strings, so that `''` can't be confused with `"` which can happen easily enough with different fonts. If you use `q{}` everywhere, you don't have to think about it.

Comment: I didn't say unreasonable. I merely said hindrances to readability. That's why I didn't change them.

Comment: Thanks again. I honestly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

And to prove that just because you can, doesn't mean you should :P

```
$string =~ s{([A-Za-z]+)([_.-]*)?}{ucfirst(lc("$1")).($2?' ':'')}ge;
```

Answer (score 0):

For all but last possibility:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file;
my $newline;

open $file, "<", "testfile";
while (<$file>) {
    chomp;
    $newline = join ' ', map ucfirst lc, split /[-_\.]/, $_;
    print $newline . "\n";
}
```